# why can't this makefile work?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I wrote the following makefile using automatic variables(`$@,$^`) and pattern(`%`),but it can't work with gnu make:

```
TARGET = edit
SRCS = $(wildcard *.c)
OBJS = $(SRCS:%.c=%.o)
$(TARGET) : $(OBJS)
    gcc $^ -o $(TARGET)
%.o : %.c
    gcc $< -c $@
```

I have foo.c ,bar.c in the working directory.
 The error is :

```
gcc foo.c -c foo.o
gcc: foo.o: No such file or directory
make: *** [foo.o] Error 1
```

I get so confused with `automatic variables` and `pattern rules`, how to use them exactly? And do they have any relationship ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're rule is wrong.  It should be:

```
%.o : %.c
    gcc -c $< -o $@
```

Comment: Thanks,I was so careless! But Why I can't see any difference when replace `gcc -c $^ -o $@` with `gcc -c $< -o $@`?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your response.  You're still seeing an error?  Can you update your question with the new error output?  What difference did you expect to see?

Comment: I think you may have mixed up what you were saying.  I think you mean "why don't I see a difference when I replace `gcc -c $< -o $@` with `gcc -c $^ -o $@`?"  So instead of looking at the first dependency, look at all of them.  The answer is that there is only one dependency for each `.o` file: the `.c` file it came from.  So there's no difference between `$^` and `$<` in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Traditional makefile syntax with all these sigils is cofusing if you're not an expert.  In [makepp](http://makepp.sourceforge.net/) you can use self explaining long names (and the 2nd line doesn't need to start with a tab):

```
%.o : %.c
    gcc -c $(input) -o $(ouptut)
```

As for your question: while these variables are useful on all rules to avoid redundancy, they are essential on pattern rules.  How else would you know which of your many input files is currently getting compiled.

*There is much more to makepp.  Besides doing almost all that GNU make can, there are lots more useful things, and you can even extend your makefiles with some Perl programming.*